# transformar un integter en un string con c

Tags: c

Estoy intentando crear un programa para transformar un `integer` en `string`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char int_to_char(int num){

    int i=0;

    for(int a=num; a!=0; i++) a/=10;

    char s[i+1];

    for(int a=num; i!=0; i--){
        s[i-1] = (a % 10) + 48;
        a/=10;
    }

    return *s;
}

int main(void){
    char a = int_to_char(123);
    printf("%c\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que hace es:

1. calcula el largo del numero.
2. crea un arreglo `s` con ese largo.
3. llena `s` con el ascii de cada numero.

El problema es que me devuelve solo el primer dígito del arreglo `s`, ¿como hago para que devuelva todo el arreglo?

Comment: Debes usar una referencia al arreglo, el método printf con el modificador %s interpreta el char[] como una cadena de caracteres.

Comment: El programa nunca hará lo que pides porque la función solo retorna un **caracter**. Lo que debes hacer es crear un *array* dinámico (lo haces con la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)) donde su tamaño dependerá del *largo del número* y por último, debes hacer que la función `int_to_char` retorna un puntero de tipo `char*`, aunque en realidad devolverá la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del *array* que hayas reservado con *malloc*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu idea es convertir un número a una cadena, necesitas devolver un array de caracteres... no únicamente un caracter:

```
   char int_to_char(int num){
// ~~~~ Solo se devuelve un caracter

    char* int_to_char(int num) {
//  ~~~~~ Ahora se devuelve una cadena de caracteres
```

Ahora bien, para gestionar las cadenas de caracteres estás recurriendo a un VLA (Variable Length Array):

```
char s[i+1];  // <<--- VLA
```

Un VLA es un array de tamaño fijo cuyo tamaño viene determinado por una variable, es decir, su tamaño se fija en tiempo de ejecución en vez de en tiempo de compilación.

Una característica de los VLA es que se crean en la pila del programa, luego su ciclo de vida está estrictamente controlado. Dicho de otra forma... como cualquier otra variable, su memoria se liberará cuando se abandone el ámbito de dicha variable.

Así que no puedes usar VLA en tu código. ¿Solución? Usa memoria dinámica:

```
char * s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i+1));
```

Claro que hay que acordarse de finalizar la cadena de caracteres con`'\0'`... nos podemos ahorrar este punto si ya dejamos correctamente inicializado el array de caracteres:

```
char * s = (char*)calloc(i+1, sizeof(char));
```

Mientras `malloc` se limita a reservar memoria dinámica, `calloc`, aparte de reservar la memoria, inicializa todas las posiciones del array en 0.

La pequeña pega que tiene gestionar memoria dinámica es que hay que acordarse de liberarla manualmente cuando ya no la necesitemos:

```
free(s);
```

Ahora bien, hay una forma más elegante de calcular el número de dígitos de un número... el logaritmo en base 10. Es facil verificar que:

```
log10(    1 ) = 0
log10(   10 ) = 1
log10(  100 ) = 2
log10( 1000 ) = 3
...
```

Así pues, solo hay que sumar uno al resultado (trabajando siempre con enteros para descartar la parte decimal) para obtener el número de dígitos de un número:

```
int i = log10(num) + 1;
```

Poniéndolo todo junto nos quedaría algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char * int_to_char(int num)
{
    int i = log10(num) + 1;
    char *s = (char*)calloc(i+1, sizeof(char));
    
    for(i--; num != 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = (num % 10) + '0';
        num/=10;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Starting...\n");
    char const* b = "Hola Mundo!";
    printf("[%s]\n", b);
    
    char *a = int_to_char(123);
    printf("[%s]\n", a);
    free(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```